How to run Python 2 and Python 3 CLI programs on Android 14 phones?
It looks like all the methods which used to work for running Python 2 and Python 3 CLI programs on Android phones is now outdated:

SL4A
QPython
Termux + python packages

I can't believe we can't run Python CLI programs on Android 14.
How would I go about it?

Termux itself may be is still a version from 2022, but the package repo like https://github.com/termux/termux-packages is still updated. Also the GitHub build system provides recent debug snapshots https://github.com/termux/termux-app/actions/workflows/debug_build.yml?query=branch%3Amaster+event%3Apush

Yes, it actually seems to work with a fresh reinstall. Before I had https/openssl version problems and I thought it's because things are out of sync.

Hi, I removed the secondary question about "similar terminal emulator environment which is current" because it's tangentially related to the main question about Python. I'd suggest posting it as another question, but unfortunately asking for apps recommendation is off-topic here. Software Recommendations SE may help in this case.

Even though the termux app hasn't been updated in over 2 years, I'd say it's still the best way to run the python cli on Android in 2024. As @Robert notes, the termux-packages repository on GitHub is still updated and provides package updates.
On a fresh install of Termux, the default bintray mirror is down and will need to be changed:
termux-change-repo
# use arrow keys and the space bar to select all 3 repos
# press enter and choose a different mirror

# Upgrade existing packages
pkg upgrade

# Install python
pkg install python

# Check python version
python -V
# 3.11.8

